# What's the proper way of showing a dialog based on a template in Onsen UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I have a one page Angular app with Onsen UI 1.3.6.

I am trying to show a dialog but I keep getting a 404 Not Found error.

My Javascript is:

```js
ons.createDialog('iconselector.html').then(function(dlg) {
  dlg.show();
});
```

And my HTML is:

```html
<ons-template id="iconselector.html" cancelable>
  <ons-dialog>
    <p>Hello world1</p>
  </ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```

I get an error stating:

> GET http://localhost/yourdomain/templates/iconselector.html 404 (Not
>   Found) startSymbol @ loader.js:1433sendReq @
>   loader.js:1432$get.serverRequest @ loader.js:1432processQueue @
>   loader.js:1433(anonymous function) @ loader.js:1433$get.Scope.$eval @
>   loader.js:1435$get.Scope.$digest @ loader.js:1435(anonymous function)
>   @ loader.js:1435completeOutstandingRequest @ loader.js:1430(anonymous
>   function) @ loader.js:1430

But if I try to show any templates as normal page using the the Tab bar's loadPage('somepage.html') method, the templates work as expected.

Comment: Is it similar to this? http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/BNGqwo

Comment: It also works in Monaca for me. Perhaps you have something else causing the errors?

Comment: I have the same code, but it does not work for me. Look at my other comment for what ended up working for me. But it's still a workaround.

Comment: Is your template in `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to create the dialog before `iconselector.html` page has been created, that's why it cannot find the page. To fix the `ons.ready()` function, which executes the code after all the DOM has been initialized. Here is an example:

```js
ons.ready(function() {   
  ons.createDialog('iconselector.html').then(function(dialog) {
    dialog.show();
  });
});
```

There are also two mistakes in your HTML:

- `cancelable` is an attribute of `ons-dialog` and not `ons-template`
- `var="dlg"` is missing in `ons-dialog` element

Here is the fixed code:

```html
<ons-template id="iconselector.html">
  <ons-dialog var="dlg" cancelable>
    <p>Hello world1</p>
  </ons-dialog>        
</ons-template>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the "cancellable". I don't know how I overlooked that. Anyway, the fix still does not work. However, what works for me is the alternative method of calling the dialog, which is to: 
1. add the a var attribute, like <ons-dialog var="someVariable">.
2. delete the surrounding <ons-template> tag altogether.
3. From Javascript, immediately call someVariable.show();

Comment: @abbood99 can you please provide all the code of your HTML page? It seems there is a problem somewhere else

Comment: So far I have not been able to isolate the code responsible for the error, and  my code is huge and cannot be pasted here. I'll keep trying to isolate it and reproduce the error. Once I do, I'll paste it here for people to benefit from.

Comment: Ok, using <script type="text/ons-template" id="iconSelector.html"> instead of <ons-template> solves the issue with ons.createDialog('iconSelector.html')...

But it's way slower than using the var.show() method.